# Using javascript confirm dialog on a button within an UpdatePanel - posting back full page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I basically want to show a dialog box with confirm or cancel options on it.

Confirm should allow the partial postback to take place, cancel should not. I have tried using a trigger and calling `__doPostBack()` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965367/partial-postback-with-javascript) but it posts back the full page not just the panel.

```
$('#buttonInUpdatePanel').live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var item = this;
    var title = 'Confirm';
    var msg = 'Please confirm something';

    var $dialog = $("<div id='myDialog'></div>")
        .html(msg)
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
         __doPostBack('Button1', null); //tried this and .submit() on the button
                    //return true;
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    //return false;
                }
            },
            title: title
        });
});
```

My UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
        <asp:Button 
            ID="Button1" 
            Text="Add" 
            OnClick="AddExtraVehicle_Click" 
            runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**UPDATE:**

I have changed the `doPostBack` to use the button ID now and commented out the return true and false lines.

When I click the button it calls the confirmation dialog but when you click on confirm it appears to do nothing. I was expecting a call to the method `AddExtraVehicle_Click` but the breakpoint didn't trigger.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: this

```
 __doPostBack('Button1', null)
```

will not work. When ASP.NET renders your Button1, the ID is not really 'Button1'. It is changed to contain the id of its naming contained. You need to do this

```
 __doPostBack($('input[id$=Button1]').attr("id"), null); //You need to use the real ID of the button which this statement will do
```

You are on the right tracks but slightly off the road :). Try this code

```
var $dialog = $("<div id='myDialog'></div>")
        .html(msg)
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
         __doPostBack($('input[id$=Button1']).attr("id"), null); //tried this and .submit() on the button
                    return true;
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            },
            title: title
        });
});
```

Basically you want to call __doPostBack with the Id of the control that has been registered as an asynch trigger of an update panel. Hope that helps!

Comment: See updated question - didn't seem to do a postback as the method did not get called (AddExtraVehicle_Click)

Comment: You are still using the wrong ID of the button for postback call. I have updated my answer. Please try that out.

Comment: I'm getting the ID from Button1.ClientID just haven't made that clear in my example sorry. MY ID is : ctl00_MainContent_ImageUploadAssignment1_ExtraRegButton

Comment: Button1.ClientID? Do you mean you are generating this JS code from server side? Would it be possible to use the code just as I provided to test quickly? I created a sampel project at my end using this exact code and everything worked! Actually ClientID could be misleading again depending on when you enumerate it in server side. Client ID can change if you use it before your button actually gets added onto a parent naming container.

Comment: Will try now. I don't generate the JS just the ID of the button as I don't want it hard coded as if the page structure changes it will break references. This is stored in a variable in my page head.

Comment: The code that I gave you will take care of the page structure changes too! In fact in a better way as you don't ahve to keep refreshing your variable that contains the ID. The ID is enumerated from the button on the run time as and when needed.

Comment: I checked using chrome developer tool and my id in the doPostBack() matches that of the button. Whats the dollar sign in your selector do BTW?

Comment: The $ sign says to filter the input buttons with an id "ending with" the text string Button1. Usually .NET ends up giving the id as "parent_parent_parent_...Button1". Does this dialogue come up in an iFrame or something in your project?

Comment: No Iframe just a standard jquery dialog (DIV). The update panel is in a usercontrol thought,would that make any difference?

Comment: Just thinking a post back wouldn't execute the click action would it? If I can get javascript to continue with the triggered click event I wouldn't need to manual trigger the postback? Any ideas?

Comment: the way .NET works, a postback executes an event handler if there is an event handler associated with the element which triggers teh postback. Hence it is necessary to get the ID of the button absolutely right in the __doPostBack call. Hold on, I just realized something. Can you publish your running sample somewhere? Honestly when I copy pasted your code exactly and used my __doPostBack version it all worked perfect.

Comment: Can't post a sample I'm afraid it's an internal project. Trying to work out what could be different in my scenario than yours. Just trying your selector method now

Comment: I can get it working by having a secondary hidden button. My first button calls the javascript dialog which when the confirm button is clicked calls triggerButton.click();  Not ideal but works...

Comment: The only thing which is probably different is the use of usercontrols and page control hierarchies. These things do introduce such hidden problems in the code. You say the update panel is in the user control, where is the AddExtraVehicle_Click defined? It should be in the same user control and marked "protected".

Comment: It is in the user control and marked as protected it triggers fine from the button when not intercepted via the javascript

Comment: Since you are trying everything, give my __doPostBack a shot as well. Sometimes it is the minutest of things that can make all the difference!

Comment: I've tried it with the selector and still have the same issue

Comment: Ahh ok. I wish I could see your source code. It is such an interesting problem. Can you copy paste the HTML of .aspx page from design time?

Comment: That would be great. nick.net@hotmail.co.uk