# How to auto post back to server every two seconds in ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have Textbox like this :

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Text1"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want my Textbox post back to server every two  every two second using set interval in javascript.

Comment: Do you mean post back to server every two second via Ajax?

Comment: @brk , already update, i mean "post back to server every two ", im so sory,

Comment: @Win, yes sir , you know what i mean. you can solve my problem ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your call to post the information you want? After that we can help with applying it to your textbox on repeat

Comment: use __doPostBack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965367/partial-postback-with-javascript and put a setInterval around it

Comment: Why you need post back the whole page instead of Ajax if you just need to deliver single value from a textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to post back a value to the server ***at certain time frame without full page post back***, you will need to use ***Ajax*** with ***WebMethod*** in ASP.NET Web Form.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Text1" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var text1 = $("#<%= Text1.ClientID %>");
    setInterval(function () {
        var data = { text: text1.val() };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebForm1.aspx/postjson") %>',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }, 10000); // Post back to server via Ajax every 10 secs
</script>
```

### Code Behind

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string PostJson(string text)
    {
        // Do something
        text += DateTime.Now;
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(text);
    }
}
```

If you get 401 error in new version of ASP.NET Web Form, then you will need to set `RedirectMode.Off`.

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; <---
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```